# Data mapping to dictionary or JSON?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, mapping

I have 2 data types. One is list of links and other is title for those links.

These are actually images links and name of the images.

Links and name of the images are scraped from different sources. You can say links are from Wikipedia and name for the images are from GitHub.

Links count and name count is same.

I am currently storing links are and image name strings in different 2 different lists.

```
images_links = [url, url2, url3]
images_names = [name, name2, name3]
```

I want the image downloader to take first the link from `images_links` and assign it a name from `images_names` and so on.

i.e., `url` → `name`, `url2` → `name2`

How can I loop through that? Should I map the data to json or dictionary to loop through it correctly?

Can anybody write a dummy code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dict(zip(images_links, images_names))
```